# SIgnalR initialization problems

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to set up SignalR but I just cant get it to work.
I am using version SignalR-2.2.2 with jQuery 3.1.1

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
```

First I have a problem with X-Content-Type-Options. This option is set to nosniff and when I reference

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

I get this in Chrome:

> Refused to execute script from '/signalr/hubs' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

And something similar in Firefox and IE.
I am not sure what to do about that.
Then just for test I removed adding X-Content-Type-Options from web config then I get the following.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that your hub container running?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: the server that contains your hub . is it running?

Comment: I think so I am doing this on my localhost.

Comment: Fine, please add the code that generates that problem!

Comment: I did the problem happens some where in what /signalr/hubs script generates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153254/discussion-between-alameerashraf-and-naruto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the problem was in my routing and not signalR. I have certain logic in Global.asax which didn't recognize signalR request and automatically send redirect response to home page which is why the script got my home page of type text/html as response.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Update all of your packages, in particular, **Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb**

Comment: I updated to the latest version  Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 3.1.0.0 but I still get the same error.